# Is there a general rule about max nr of variables to use in (generalized) linear model?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, sample-size, interaction, linear-model

I am running a generalized linear model on a dataset with 19 individuals and have 4 variables of interest. There are furthermore a number of interactions that might be interesting to look at. I was wondering if there is a general rule of thumb (with reference please) about the nr of terms you can use in a model based on the sample size. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Tukey's suggestion of a minimum of 5 observations per mean parameter (he also suggested 25 observations per variance or covariance parameter). I don't recall the exact location of that suggestion, sorry.

But it really depends on the accuracy you want. If you want to be able to get a reasonable idea of actual effects sizes, [this](http://www.surefoss.org/visualisation/evolution-of-a-logistic-regression/) suggests that for a logistic regression something more like 50 observations per parameter might be more in the ballpark.

[This](http://www.nrcse.washington.edu/research/struts/chapter2.pdf) has sample-size-related rules of thumb; if you can specify the required information you might be able to figure out what you need.

Comment: Harrell has similarish ROTs (with citations): http://books.google.com/books?id=kfHrF-bVcvQC&lpg=PA61&ots=34KVS2ehF-&dq=frank%20harrell%20table%204.1%20limiting%20sample%20size&pg=PA61&output=embed